# Specify an index blacklist when searching with ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, search, indexing, blacklist

An Elasticsearch query can cross multiple indexes with wild cards or multiple index specifications:

```
GET /index1,index2,indexwithwildcard*/_search
```

Is there some way to specify a list of indexes *not* to search, such that all indexes not in that list are searched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, by [prepending `-`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-index.html) before the index name. Below, the search will exclude `index3`

```
GET /index1,index2,indexwithwildcard*,-index3/_search
```